# Custom TOC and Chapter Heading style with memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, memoir, chapters

In order to have a better style of pages (chapter, section) using memoir, is it possible to get a style like this (picture 1 and 2 below) in TeX ?

Also, I want to create a general introduction just like where it's writen "Avant-propos" . And i want to delete the " Partie 1 , Partie 2 ,..." and keep the rest as it's writen.

And in the chapter heading style, in the picture below, i wanted to have something like that (see picture 2) with the number and the name of the chapter and the list of the sections and subsections just below.

- Picture 1: Table of contents style.
  [image]
- Picture 2 : Chapter heading style.
  [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Indeed, the basic answer to your question is: *"yes, it is possible!"*. I think you rather wanted to ask *"how is it possible to do the same?"*. In this case, providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is the best way to get an answer. You might also show some efforts in the question, and not just ask *"do it for me plz!"*. To format headings, you can have a look at the `titlesec` package!

Comment: Welcome, unless a member of this community is really really bored this weekend, you won't get an answer. Someone could give a few pointers, but that won't answer the question. Right now, it is either: Yes, it can be done (Answer: yes) or a *Do it for me* question, which we don't like.

Comment: You will find more information about the `titlesec` package on the dedicated [CTAN repository](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). You're lucky, the manual is really explanatory and you have plenty examples at the end.

Comment: Hi again, i didn't want you guys to do this at 100% for me, of course i will try this by myself, but right now i didn't have much time i'm woriking on something else. I just wanted some help so i can start because i don't know how to do this, what packages should i use and other stuffs. Thanks for reading my question :)

Comment: The `memoir` document class has several different styles for titles. Read the documentation, and the LaTeX code for those styles (which is listed in the documentation). The `menukeys` package might be useful for creating the colored background to "Chapitre 1", etc.

Comment: Isn't it a bit ... er ... lurid? Note that the `Plan`, if that's part of what you want has extremely poor contrast. You should pay some heed to the needs of users with visual impairments.